# How to use global variable in Matlab in such situations

Tags: matlab

I'm using a CMA-ES optimization procedure on https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cmaes.m

if i define a function

```
function y = myfun(x)
    y = (x(1)-1)^2+(x(2)-2)^2;
end
```

then use cmaes I can use

```
function X = optimise(myfun)
    X = cmaes(myfun,[0 0]',3.0);
end

optimies('myfun')
```

to find the optimal solution.

However, If I have such a suituation:

```
function y = myfun(x)
    global a b;
    y = (x(1)-a)^2+(x(2)-b)^2;
end
```

and

```
function X = optimise()
    global a b;
    a = 10;
    b = 1;
    X = cmaes(myfun,[0 0]',3.0);
end
```

There will be an error.

I think it is because cmaes function does not have global definitions.
But just adding 
    global a b
to cmaes.m does not work

Can anyone help me out this problem?

Comment: Your example code is not running as supplied. In the first `optimise`, the `cmaes` call is misspelled as `cames`, and it looks like `myfun` needs to be referenced as `@myfun` (a function handle) or `'myfun'` (a string) in both cases. Can you re-check your code?

Comment: And what error are you getting? Globals function fine like that (though they're not great program design). The error is somewhere else.